# Delete rows to keep only top values in a sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to have some product recommendations in my website. I have this table that i have generated but need to keep a limited amount of entries.

The table consists of these columns (filling with some random values):

```
ID | Product ID | Related Product ID | Score
1  |         10 |                111 |   0.1
2  |         10 |                123 |   0.4
3  |         10 |                124 |   0.5
4  |         10 |                125 |   0.4
5  |         10 |                126 |   0.2
6  |         10 |                127 |   0.4
7  |         11 |                111 |   0.1
8  |         12 |                123 |   0.4
```

How can i trucate top 10 SCORE values for each PRODUCT ID in this table?

Comment: What do you mean by "trucate [sic] top 10 SCORE values for each PRODUCT ID in this table"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have more than 1k rows for each product ID with different score (which is the relevance of the related product 0.1-0.9). I need to keep the most relevant entries and to delete the rest because my table has more than 1 million rows.

Comment: `Truncate` in DB terms means *empty the entire table of all data*. You're looking for `DELETE` with a `WHERE` clause that identifies the rows to remove.

Comment: Are you removing the rows from the table, or simply not wanting to show them to show in a query result you display on your website?

Comment: How are you inserting the values? Are you wanting to retain the top 10 (based on what?) of each `Product ID` or just 10 records total? As mentioned [TRUNCATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_(SQL)) has a very specific meaning in SQL. Please update your question with an example showing an undesired dataset and another example of a desired result. As it stands right now, you are showing only 8 rows with no real insight on what you're expecting after the "truncate".

Comment: @KenWhite sorry i am trying to delete a part of the data. I know this is a very beginner issue but im not finding the right query to keep top 10 for each product ID. Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note -- you did not say what platform, the following will work in SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 and others

The following statement will give you the top 10 ten rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY SCORE DESC) AS RN
  FROM SOME_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
) X
WHERE X.RN < 11
```

So then delete everything else

```
DELETE FROM SOME_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
  SELECT ID
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY SCORE DESC) AS RN
    FROM SOME_TABLENAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
  ) X
  WHERE X.RN < 11
)
```

Comment: Hogan, mysql is tagged as the platform.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. this is exactly what i was trying to do.

Comment: @SonnGoR -- Welcome to stack overflow, when something is what you want you should up vote it and mark it as correct.